# How to identify GET/POST requests made by a human ignoring any requests following

Tags: c++, http

I'm writing an application that listens to HTTP traffic and tries to recognize which requests where initiated by a human.

For example:
The user types *cnn.com* in their address bar, which starts a request. Then I want to find
*CNN's* server response while discarding any others requests (such as XHR, etc.)

How could you tell from the header information what means what?

After doing some research I've found that relevant responses come with :

1. Content-Type: text/html
2. Html comes with a meaningful title
3. status 200 ok

Comment: Could you provide us with more information? In what language are you trying to achieve this...

Comment: I'm writing in C++ but it doesn't really matter, I have at hand a structure that holds all the mime information: http header, http body.

Comment: Actually it matters a lot. You're asking how to determine something, so that would mean code-wise. In that case you should include the language you're trying to achieve this in.

Comment: @ArtaexMedia: The problem here seems to be figuring out how to interpret TCP packets (or maybe HTTP); this is pretty-much language-agnostic...

Comment: My application is totally passive towards the traffic, all it does is to decide which request/response to record. Nevertheless, I'm using c++ and I use mimetic parser to parse the http mime.

Comment: This is very much impossible. What problem are you tying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to build an application that will record my browsing history just from listening to the wire

Comment: I'd guess there would be a browser plugin to do something like that.

Comment: obviously every browser does it but I want to build a system wide application: multiple users, multiple browsers.

Comment: You can only do that approximately, using heuristics. Record everything that has no `Referer` (users can switch `Referer` off, but it's their choice to use, misuse or not use your service). Record everything that was sent after a pause. Ignore everything that was sent within a very short time from an initial request and has a `Referer` set to the URL of that request. Ignore everything that gets a response with code &gt;=300. You are going to have lots of fun fine-tuning your parameters and tweaking the rules.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell from the bits on the wire.  The HTTP protocol has a defined format, which all (non-broken) user agents adhere to.

You are probably thinking that the translation of a user's typing of just 'cnn.com' into 'http://www.cnn.com/' on the wire can be detected from the protocol payload.  The answer is no, it can't.

To detect the user agent allowing the user such shorthand, you would have to snoop the user agent application (e.g. a browser) itself.

Actually, detecting non-human agency is the interesting problem (with spam detection as one obvious motivation).  This is because HTTP belongs to the family of NVT protocols, where the basic idea, believe it or not, is that a human should be able to run the protocol "by hand" in a network terminal/console program (such as a telnet client.)  In other words, the protocol is basically designed as if a human were using it.

Comment: I've added a para about the design origins of the protocol.  Basically the protocol is designed to look like a human is using it, because a human is _supposed_ to be able to use it manually in something like a telnet client.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think header information can suffice to identify real users from bots, since bots are made to mimic real users and headers are very easy to imitate.

One thing you can do, is to track the path (sequence of clicks) followed by a user, which is most likely to be different from one made by a bot, and made some analysis on the posted information (i.e. bayesian filters).

A very easy to implement check is based on the IP source. There are databases of black listed IP addresses, see [Project Honeypot](https://www.projecthoneypot.org/) - and if you are writing your software in java, here is an example on how to check an IP address: [How to query HTTP:BL for spamming IP addresses](http://en.newinstance.it/2012/04/18/how-to-query-httpbl-for-spamming-ip-addresses/).

What I do on my blog is this (using wordpress plugins):

1. check if an IP address is in the HTTP:BL, if it is the user is shown an html page to take action to whitelist his IP address. This is done in Wordpress by [Bad Behavior](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bad-behavior/) plugin.
2. when the user submits some content, a bayesian filter verifies the content of his submission and if his comment is identified as spam, a captcha is displayed before completing the submission. This is done with [akismet](http://akismet.com/) and [conditional captcha](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-conditional-captcha/), and the comment is also enqueued for manual approval.
3. After being approved once, the same user is considered safe, and can post without restrictions/checks.

Applying the above rules, I have nomore spam on my blog. And I think that a similar logic can be used for any website.

The advantage of this approach, is that most of the users don't even notice any security mechanism, since no captcha is displayed, nor anything unusual happens in 99% of the times. But still there is quite restrictive, and effective, checks going on under the hoods.

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer any code to help, but I'd say look at the `Referer` HTTP header. The initial `GET` request shouldn't have a `Referer`, but when you start loading the resources on the page (such as JavaScript, CSS, and so on) the `Referer` will be set to the URL that requested those resources.

So when I type in "stackoverflow.com" in my browser and hit enter, the browser will send a `GET` request with no `Referer`, like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
# ... other Headers
```

When the browser loads the supporting static resources on the page, though, each request will have a `Referer` header, like this:

```
GET /style.css HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
Referer: http://www.stackoverflow.com
# ... other Headers
```

Comment: When you click on a link, `Referer` is also sent.

Comment: Referer is an optional field.  There is nothing mandating its presence in a HTTP request.  Web designers relying on it are morons.

Comment: Yeah this might have a more limited use than I thought. It can detect if a user typed the URL in their address bar, but it won't work for clicked links. Also depends on the client's user-agent (works fine if you're using Chrome.)

Comment: All decent browsers (Firefox, Opera, etc) allow suppression of the Referer field in requests. There are [security considerations](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html) too.  Neither the presence nor the absence of the Referer field can reliably imply anything.